# Css3 Flexbox 3 column layout small width, stretch middle one and width: max-200px on right

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a 3 column row layout in flexbox.

The left column needs to be 60px width and not larger.

Then the center column needs to stretch 100% and the right column need to be on the right and no more than 200px width.

```
| width: 60px | Stretch 100%                           |  width: max-200px |
```

Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>LEFT</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 7">MIDDLE</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 2">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

}

.flex-container > div {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

At this moment the middle div is not expanding so it pushes the right column to the right.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust your code like below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-container>div {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.flex-container>div:first-child {
   width:60px; /*fixed width*/
   flex-shrink:0; /*avoid shriking*/
}
.flex-container>div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow:1; /*can grow*/
}
.flex-container>div:nth-child(3) {
  flex-grow:1;  /*can grow*/
  max-width:200px; /*max-width*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>LEFT</div>
  <div>MIDDLE</div>
  <div>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

by using flex:0 0 auto on the element you specify that the width should be 'defined' by its content and/or css width properties (width / min-width / max-width)

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.container div{
  height:500px;
}
.container__left{
  background-color:red;
  width:60px;
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
.container__center{
  background-color:green;
  flex:1;
}
.container__right{
  background-color:blue;
  max-width:200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__left">left</div>
  <div class="container__center">center</div>
  <div class="container__right">right and other things in here that should be no more than 200px</div>
</div>
```